# Why does pallet-election-phragmen have a Balance field in it's Genesis Config?

Tags: frame, pallet-election-phragmen

Why does `pallet-election-phragmen` have a Balance field here?

```rust
   #[pallet::genesis_config]
    pub struct GenesisConfig<T: Config> {
        pub members: Vec<(T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>)>,
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This `BalanceOf<T>` represents the stake of each member in the first election.

Comment: So for voting one requires to bond some amount?